# JInternalFrame inside JInternal frame not shown

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that is extending JInternalFrame which also holds a JDesktopPane that should hold another JInternalFrame which can be added on a button click.

I can log that the JInternalFrame is constructed, but it is not shown on its parent JInternalFrame and I dont know why.

Here are the relevant sections:

Parent class

```
    this.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(tableScrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(desktop,BorderLayout.SOUTH);       //The parents Desktop pane to which I want to add internalframes on button click
```

The method that should add a new JInternalFrame to the desktop (JDesktopPane of parent)

```
 private void addChart(Market market){
    this.desktop.add(new Chart(market.getSymbol(),this.quoteMarket, Indicators.convertToTa4JBarSeries(market.getSymbol(),market.getCandles())));
}
```

The JInternalFrame class that should be created and visible on the parents desktop pane. The constructor gets called, I can see that in the log section.

```
public class Chart extends JInternalFrame {
public Chart(String title, String quoteMarket,BarSeries barSeries){
    System.out.println("Chart created");
    setTitle(title + " " + quoteMarket);
    setSize(500,500);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setClosable(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    this.displayChart(title,quoteMarket,barSeries);
    this.pack();
    this.show();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I figured out once I set prefferedSize to the desktop the InternalFrames are showing and the desktoppane itself as well. But what I am actually after is to adjust the size based on its content (the InternalFrames) once they get added. Is there any way to do this, as I dont want to initially set a size of the desktopPane when there is nothing inside of it.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: *I dont want to initially set a size of the desktopPane when there is nothing inside of it.* -  Add a `ContainerListener` to the desktop pane and handle the two events to set the preferred size as requirement. You would then need to `revalidate()` to make sure the layout manager is invoked.